# When exporting the product, the exported CSV file is too small and the content is incomplete

Tags: product, csv, export

The version of my magento2 is 2.3.5-p1.

My export steps are as follows:

1. System ->Export
2. Select 'Products' for Entity Type
3. Select 'CSV' for Export File Format, there is only one option available here for CSV
4. Click on 'Continue'
5. Operation successful, prompt 'Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon. Make sure your cron job is running to export the file'

After a while, a download record was generated, but the downloaded file was only 223KB. Previously, the file size that was normally downloaded was around 15MB.

The exported file is missing many columns. In the exported file, only two columns' configurable_variables and configurable_variation_labels' have content, while the contents of the other columns are empty.

Does someone has the same issue and were able to fix it? Any ideas how to fix it?

I am happy for any ideas!

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Check this article, This seems to be the same issue as yours.
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/miscellaneous/exported-products-.csv-file-does-not-appear.html?lang=en

Comment: Hi , may i suggest you to please check the error logs ? Or debug the whole export process using xdebugger and check for exceptions.